# Installing MySQL-python via yum / missing dependency / incompatibility?

Tags: mysql, centos, python, yum

I have come up against problems installing MySQL-python via yum.

Our server is running Centos 5.5 and MySQL Version 5.1.45, Python-dev is
installed.

Yum complains about the missing dependency libmysqlclient_r.so.15:

```
Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package
MySQL-python-1.2.1-1.x86_64 (base)
```

The server is up to date and the packages mysql mysql-devel
python-devel are installed. The missing dependency is nowhere on the system:

```
# locate libmysqlclient
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.la
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.a
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.la
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/local/cpanel/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.14
```

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
MySQL-devel-5.1.45-0.glibc23
MySQL-bench-5.0.89-0.glibc23
MySQL-shared-5.1.45-0.glibc23
MySQL-server-5.1.45-0.glibc23
MySQL-test-5.1.45-0.glibc23
MySQL-client-5.1.45-0.glibc23
```

The Python version is python-2.4.3-27.el5.x86_64:

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep  3 2009, 15:37:37)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of MySQL-python requires older version of mysql than yours.

So you either need newer version of MySQL-python or older mysql.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought that might be an issue. Are you aware of a yum repository with a newer version or will I have to compile from source? We can't downgrade our MySQL at this time.

Comment: No, but check rpmfind.net and rpm.pbone.net - perhaps not for CentOS, but something else like Fedora

Comment: i have a same problem. My python is 2.6.4 and my mysql installed with distrbu 5.0.77 but i installed latest version of mysqldb-python1.2.3. Still i am getting same error on yum install and gcc exit with status 1 on manual installation of the same. can u please guide me? my question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952965/mysqldb-python-2-6-says-gcc-exit-with-status-1

Comment: please see my problem here also http://serverfault.com/questions/325928/gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-mysql-python-1-2-3