# 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 - MySQL-python-1.2.3

Tags: python, gcc, mod-python

I am installing MySQL db for python2.6. I installed it from [here](http://ben.timby.com/?p=123) but when I am on the line

I extracted the file and when I did

```
python2.6 setup.py build
```

it gives a lot of errors and warring and end with some of the lines

```
_mysql.c: At top level:
_mysql.c:2331: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âopenâ
_mysql.c:2338: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âconverterâ
_mysql.c:2345: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âconnectionâ
_mysql.c:2352: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âconnectionâ
_mysql.c:2359: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âconnectionâ
_mysql.c:2422: error: â_mysql_ResultObjectâ has no member named âconverterâ
_mysql.c:2422: error: initializer element is not constant
_mysql.c:2422: error: (near initialization for â_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[0].offsetâ)
_mysql.c: In function â_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattrâ:
_mysql.c:2444: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âopenâ
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

***EDIT***

command

```
# yum --enablerepo=smartfile install MySQL-python26
```

it says

```
 perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by   package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 (installed)
 php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by package php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (installed)
 mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386 from base has depsolving problems
--> mysql conflicts with MySQL-server
 php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
 --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package php-mysql- 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (installed)
 perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
 --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package perl-DBD-  MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 (installed)
 MySQL-python-1.2.1-1.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by package MySQL-python-1.2.1-1.x86_64 (installed)
 MySQL-python-1.2.1-1.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
 --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package MySQL-   python-1.2.1-1.x86_64 (installed)
 Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by package MySQL-python-1.2.1-1.x86_64 (installed)
 Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 (installed)
 Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package MySQL-python-1.2.1-1.x86_64 (installed)
 Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (installed)
 Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server
 Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by package php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (installed)
 Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 (installed)
```

but when I located sqlclient I got

```
[root@domain ~]locate libmysqlclient
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0
```

How I can provide link to this?
***EDIT 2***

command

```
 [root@domain /]# yum whatprovides libmysqlclient.so.15
```

says

```
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.steadfast.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.wiredtree.com
   base             | 1.1 kB     00:00
   chl              |  951 B     00:00
   chl-source       |  951 B     00:00
   epel             | 3.7 kB     00:00
   epel/primary_db  | 3.8 MB     00:00
   extras           | 2.1 kB     00:00
   smartfile        |  951 B     00:00
   updates          | 1.9 kB     00:00
   mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
   Repo        : base
   Matched from:
   Other       : libmysqlclient.so.15
```

***EDIT 3***

```
[root@domain ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
```

yeilds

```
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6
mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6
mysql-devel-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6
perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5
php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3
```

means mysql and mysql-server are both of same version.

Comment: So the code you're trying to compile has a problem. you have four choices: (1) Debug it yourself, (2) report the problem to the developers & wait for a fix, (3) try a newer/older release & see if it compiles, (4) try an alternate installation method (like the package system for your OS)

Comment: What is the output of `yum whatprovides libmysqlclient.so.15`?

Comment: Note the following error: "mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386 from base has depsolving problems  
--> mysql conflicts with MySQL-server"

Comment: please see my edit 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [smartfile](http://dagobah.ftphosting.net/yum/) repo, then why not install MySQL-python from that:

```
# yum --enablerepo=smartfile install MySQL-python26
```

Comment: please see my edit.

Comment: thanks for the reply. please see my post, i edited it again.